# how to call initstate or didchangedependencies after pop stack

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using bloc design pattern and when i navigate screen 2 from screen 1 then the dispose method is triggering so my stream is closing. after i am poping from screen 2 then i return the screen 1. but in this case my bloc is still in memory and when i want to add a data to stream i receive `Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close` error. i need to call initstate or didchangedependecies method after popping to initialize my bloc again. is there a way to do that?

shortly i need to init my bloc again. this is what i tried. But this methods doesn't trigger after the pop from another screen.

```
 DeckBloc deckBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    deckBloc = new DeckBloc();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    deckBloc = new DeckBloc();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when your're about to navigate to second page to begin with await the result and re initialize your bloc in the result callback of the navigation you made.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed<void>('second page route')
  .then((result){
     //this block of code will run when you pop from the second page and navigate back here
     //initialize your bloc here
     deckBloc = new DeckBloc();
   });
```

Comment: glad i could be of help